# Excel cell value and formula bar display different data

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, csv

I have a csv file which when opened gives an incomplete data as the cell value, the hour portion of timestamp is missing to be exact.

[image: the hour portion of timestamp is missing to be exact.]

However the complete timestamp can be seen in the formula bar. If I click on the cell, and start to edit the data then the hour part reappears.

[image: If I click on the cell, and start to edit the data then the hour part reappears.]

Any idea why this happens??

The date seems to have some issues too, it is displayed as ######### , however opening the cell and pressing enter key seems to solve that problem. 
CSV file is generated from a batch script by the way

Comment: When the column is too narrow for the date field to be visible, it's normal to display it as `######`. Make the column wider to see the value.

Comment: The display of the hour portion is probably controlled by the formatting rule defined for the cell or the entire column.

Comment: thank you very much., i changed the default format for time and now things are all ok..

Comment: Great! I made my tips an answer. If this answered your question, then please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the column is too narrow for the date field to be visible, it's normal to display it as `######`. Make the column wider to see the value.

The display of the hour portion is controlled by the formatting rule defined for the cell or the entire column.
You can adjust it according to your need.